# add to cart button for product list page

Tags: magento-1, cart, product-view

.what steps should I consider the description of ADD TO CART BUTTON  for category page and product list page step by step.

Comment: What you want to know about 'Add to cart functionality" ? if you are having problem in any specific part then please provide more detail it will be easier to provide solution.

Comment: For documentation you can easily find lot of resources on magento 1 however if you want to study about magento 2 then magento dev docs will be of great help : you can find all docs / resources here https://magento.com/resources/technical

Comment: Your question is very broad, please provide clear technical details with which we can help you.

Comment: .what steps should I consider about ADD TO CART BUTTON  in catogery page and  product list page